# What is callback function in AJAX? How to implement a callback function in PreSaveAction function of SP2013 list NewForm?

Tags: ajax, callback, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I want to store the value of a variable and use it outside the ajax call. But being an asynchronous call it is giving me initial value of that variable. I am implementing my custom code for some validations in PreSaveAction function since I have to do validations on Save button click of SharePoint NewForm,Following is my code,

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var titleItem;
    var flg=0;
    var dataFromServer;


 function PreSaveAction()
 {

    titleItem = $("input[title='Title']").val();    


    $.ajax({

                url:"http://sp13dev:4149/Appraisals/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('SkillMaster')/items?$select=Id,Title&$filter=Title eq '"+titleItem+"'" ,
            type: "GET",
            async: false,
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",  
                        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose", 
                        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val() },
            success: function (data) {



                if(data.d.results.length>=1)
                {
                    flg=1;
                    $("#labelTitle").html("Skill already exists. Please enter another name.");

                }
                else
                {
                    flg=0;     
                    $("#labelTitle").html("");          

                }

            },
           error: function (error) {

                alert(JSON.stringify(error));
            }

        }); 


        if(flg==1)
        {

        //  $("#labelTitle").html("Skill already exists. Please enter another name.");
            return false;
        }       

    return true;

 }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have misplaced your return call. You should have your return placed inside your

```
if(data.d.results.length>=1)
```

statement inside the success callback function.